# Read uncommited rows created by postgresql function?

Tags: postgresql, function, transactions, read-uncommitted

I wrote a function that creates a row in the table `mytable` accordingly to the parameters and returns the id of the created row.

Unfortunately, if I use the following statement, the `SELECT` returns no row, as if the transaction of the function was different from the one of the `SELECT`.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = createComplexRow(...);
```

My understanding was that I was running the same transaction for the select and the function and then should be able to read uncommitted rows.

I am trying with postgres 9.6

Any clue how to make it works properly ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's look at what is going on.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   val timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);

CREATE FUNCTION createcomplexrow() RETURNS integer
   LANGUAGE SQL AS
'INSERT INTO mytable (val) VALUES (current_timestamp) RETURNING id';
```

The function is implicitly `VOLATILE`, as it has to be, since it modifies the database.

Let's insert a few rows:

```
SELECT createcomplexrow();
SELECT createcomplexrow();
```

Now let's try your statement:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = createcomplexrow();

 id | val
----+-----
(0 rows)
```

Indeed, no result!

But there are new values in the table:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;

 id |              val
----+-------------------------------
  1 | 2017-07-18 11:50:22.031922+02
  2 | 2017-07-18 11:50:23.640775+02
  3 | 2017-07-18 11:50:31.392773+02
  4 | 2017-07-18 11:50:31.392773+02
(4 rows)
```

To see what happens, `EXPLAIN` the query:

```
EXPLAIN (COSTS off)
   SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = createcomplexrow();

             QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on mytable
   Filter: (id = createcomplexrow())
(2 rows)
```

PostgreSQL scans the table, and for each row found, it calls the function and compares the result to the `id` of the row.

When it scans the row with `id = 1`, the function will return 3 (and insert a row). So the row with `id = 1` is skipped.

Similarly, the row with `id = 2` is skipped, and a new row with `id = 4` is created.

Now why does execution stop here rather than proceed to scan the two newly created rows?

These [lines from the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED) explain it somewhat:

> In effect, a `SELECT` query sees a snapshot of the database as of the instant the query begins to run.
>   However, `SELECT` does see the effects of **previous updates** executed within its own transaction, even though they are not yet committed.

(emphasis mine)

The statement doesn't see the effect of the function because the function is not executed in a *previous update*, but in the *same statement* as the `SELECT`.

(The same happens in [data modifying `WITH` queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING); you may find reading that part of the documentation enlightening.)

Actually, you should be glad that it is handled that way, otherwise you'd end up with an endless loop that continues inserting rows into the table.

Comment: The question is what you are trying to achieve. You certainly don't want an endless loop, do you?

Comment: of course not, the actual use case is more `UPDATE mytable SET specific WHERE id = createComplexRow(...)` and I'd like to do that in regular sql (not in a function)

Comment: well, i'll use a `DO` block to store the value and split the request into two, thx

Comment: You could either first enter the rows and then update them in a different SQL statement or (better) insert the correct values right away and not update the new rows. Another option is a `BEFORE` trigger that modifies the values that should be inserted.